# Store multiple dynamic EditText value

Tags: android

I have a code adding multiple EditText. How can i store them into a array. This number 10 is just example, the number may bigger than that. How can i store it after click a button

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    String store[] = new String[10];
    EditText addAnsMCQ = new EditText(this);      
    AnswerRG.addView(addAnsMCQ, 1);
    addAnsMCQ.setWidth(200);
    addAnsMCQ.setId(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the store variable isn't actually being used, did you intend do use it for storing the EditTexts?

Instead of using an array of `String`, just use an array of `EditText` and store a reference to them:

```
EditText store[] = new EditText[10];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    EditText addAnsMCQ = new EditText(this);     
    AnswerRG.addView(addAnsMCQ, 1);
    addAnsMCQ.setWidth(200);
    addAnsMCQ.setId(1000);
    store[i] = addAnsMCQ; //store a reference in the array to the EditText created
}
```

Then outside of the for loop, you can access the reference to each `EditText`, e.g.

```
store[0].setWidth(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep/get a reference to each of your EditText's then you can look up its value with .getText().toString() which you can store in whatever manner you like.

However if as you say

> This number 10 is just example, the number may bigger than that.

If the number is going to be larger you should be using an Adapter and a ListView or something to hold your View objects. That will make it easier to get everything on to the screen. And will give you the benefit of view recycling.